# how to correctly address -Wcast-qual

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have a variable `k` of type `const char *`, and a function in glib with the prototype

```
void g_hash_table_replace(GHashTable *hash_table,
                          gpointer key,
                          gpointer value);
```

`gpointer` is defined simply as

```
typedef void* gpointer;
```

I know that in this case it is, in fact, okay to pass in `k` as the key in `g_hash_table_replace`, however gcc gives me the error

```
service.c:49:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘g_hash_table_replace’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghash.h:70:13: note: expected ‘gpointer’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
```

this is with gcc 4.6.0.  With 4.5.0 and earlier, a simple cast to (char *) sufficed to supress this warning, but gcc seems to have gotten 'smarter'.  I've tried `(char *)(void *)k`, but it still knows that the variable was originally `const`.  What is the best way to silence this warning without calling `strdup(3)` on `k`?

Comment: Why silence the warning ? It indicates a real problem : you are casting away the `const` qualifier, which is potentially dangerous. Instead of silencing the warning, why not resolve the issue that causes the warning (either make the function accept a pointer-to-const, or pass a non-const) ?

Comment: I can't modify the function, its in an external library (glib).  And I can't remove the `const` without making a copy of the string - its a compile-time string constant stored in a read-only section in my executable.  But glib also doesn't modify the argument (even though its not marked as `const`) - I've both read the code for `GHashTable` and used my code as-is for months.  Since the warning isn't applicable in this situation, I'd rather silence it rather than do a string-copy with `strdup(3)` before calling the function.

Comment: I don't have a gcc 4.6.0 available atm, but does `const_cast<char*>(k)` get rid of the warning ?

Comment: Sander: sorry, this is straight C, not C++.  However, basically I'm looking for the equivalent in C.

Comment: Indeed - I don't know why I thought this question was about C++. You can probably disable the warning with the `-Wno-cast-qual` command-line option or by using `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-qual"` in the code for just the parts where you want the warning disabled.

Comment: @Bobby Powers: It's probably worth a bug report to the glib maintainers - since this function just takes a pointer from you and returns it later, it should work the same way as functions like `strchr()` do - taking a `const`-qualified argument and returning a non-qualified result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this with gcc 4.6.1.

```
#include <glib/ghash.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char *k="Testing";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int val = 1024;

    GHashTable *hash_table=NULL;
    g_hash_table_replace(hash_table,(gpointer) (intptr_t)k, &val);

    return 0;
}
```

Without casts, the error is as you describe above.  But if I cast the `const char*` to `intptr_t` first as shown above, the warning is suppressed.  Can you confirm that you still experience the error with my code sample?